# Configuration file vs Registry for saving configrable values in C# .net

Tags: c#, registry, configuration-files

I am working on a project which has multiple components like windows service, web service and web interface. I have some common configuration values for all these components. Also I have to change the value periodically. As I have to change the values in all the applications, I am thinking of saving the common values in registry. Is there any disadvantage of saving the values in registry? Could anyone tell me the pros and cons of doing so.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of disadvantages to registry config. You can't easily port your configuration to a new environment, you need to implement some sort of UI to allow user edits, registry access requires permissions your end user may not have on their machine.

Use a configuration file (e.g; xml) for local configuration, or a database if you need centralised configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Using registry settings makes your deployment difficult. You have to handle it in setup and also during uninstall process.

It is better to have a smaller footprint on the client's machine.